# How does 'telnet localhost' work?

Tags: networking, server, client, sockets

I created a simple server program and connects a client to it using terminal. In the terminal window, the command `telnet localhost [port number]` was used. Can anyone please tell me how this command works?

Suppose i create a server via one terminal window, and can i connect a client to it using another terminal window opened in another computer, connected to internet through another router? Please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is just a name for the **local host**. If you look into `/etc/hosts` you will find a line

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Connections to `localhost` don't use the real network - you won't see anything on the wire from them.

If you want to connect to your server from another machine on your network, you must know the IP address of your server (you can get it with `ip address show`) (e.g. `192.168.13.45`) and then type `telnet 192.168.13.45 [portnumber]`.

Comment: Thanx, @guntbert I had the same question ,, well is there any way to send the request(telnet )  from any specific port number??

Comment: Why would you need that? Usually the client uses a (random) port number for the outgoing request, and the server doesn't care about it.

Comment: can you please refer to my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/547105/how-to-fix-a-port-no-statically-for-client-request-on-client-side

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551662/what-happens-in-the-network-when-i-access-port-on-localhost-using-telnet